# gactions list ERROR: The caller does not have permission

Tags: actions-on-google

gactions cli Oauth processing is broken for me - it's unable to connect after following the initialization directions:

```
$ gactions --verbose list --project JovoTest
Checking for updates...
Successfully fetched update metadata
Finished checking for updates -- no updates available
Reading credentials from: creds.data
Gactions needs access to your Google account. Please copy & paste the URL below into a web browser and follow the instructions there. Then copy and paste the authorization code from the browser back here.
Visit this URL: 
 https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=237807841406-o6vu1tjkq8oqjub8jilj6vuc396e2d0c.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&response_type=code&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Factions.builder&state=state 
Enter authorization code: 
4/AACp4YGiTu6LNJGbNBU3qV3hDbLL4a4d5SuN72UuIO6fXESUChlTF5s
Saving credentials to: creds.data
GET /v2/agents/JovoTest/versions?pageSize=10 HTTP/1.1
Host: actions.googleapis.com
User-Agent: Gactions-CLI/2.1.3 (darwin; amd64; stable/dff629ae63fd0b047d19687b79274524569714e6)
Accept-Encoding: gzip


ERROR: Couldn't fetch versions
ERROR: The caller does not have permission
2018/06/26 12:43:02 Server did not return HTTP 200
```

Comment: Hi @ohmi am getting "Access blocked: Assistant CLI’s request is invalid" message while copy paste the URL in browser. How can I resolve this. I tried OOB as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is related to authentication of the tool. I believe that the project you're setting up does not have any versions of the action available. I tried with a number of my own projects:

`~/Downloads/gactions list --project assistant-sdk-project`

```
ERROR: Couldn't fetch versions
ERROR: Requested entity was not found.
```

`~/Downloads/gactions list --project felker-action-1`

```
Version           Create Time   Update Time  Approval  Deployment Status
v-[1]-2018-03-10  3 months ago  1 month ago  APPROVED  DEPLOYED
```

What do you currently have set up for your action?

Comment: Nothing -- I just created it from the tutorials through to testing in the simulator. Do i have to do the whole deployment exercise?

Comment: If you do not have any versions set up, then there are no versions to list. Once you deploy a project you should see a version show up.

Comment: So, in your opinion, how can the inquirer make versions of his action available?

Comment: Once you deploy a project you should see a version appear in the list. Until that point, there are no _versions_.

Comment: Hi @NickFelker I am getting "Access blocked: Assistant CLI’s request is invalid" message while copy paste the URL in browser. How can I resolve this. I tried OOB as well –